# How can I move part of my armature and change the origin of the bones

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

This is my first time posting here.
I ran into a problem with my armature, im sure it's an easy fix.
I've done modification to my character, now i want to realign my armature to my new character.
I want to lower the arm bones to meet my mesh, but bones won't move all together, as if they have different origin or something.
In edit mode, i can get what i want, but when i switch to pose/object mode, the bones are not where i need them to be !
Thanks for helping out a complete noob :D

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, it's probably due to the IK constraint or another constraint, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=d0n2LoGA" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/d0n2LoGA/)

Comment: @moonboots here is the file. 
Thank you so much for helping out, my friend. <3

Comment: If your bones have constraints like IK constraints or Copy Location, and if they don't stick to their target bones in Edit mode, they will stick to them as soon as you switch to Pose mode, so you need to be sure that they do stick to their target, I suspect this is the problem here